# How to change style in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with my code? I am trying to change the sizes of two boxes when the button is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javaScript> 
    document.getElementById("makesmaller").onclick=function(){
        document.getElementById("bigbox").style.size="100px".color="green";
    }

    document.getElementById("makebig").onclick=function(){
        document.getElementById("littlebox").style.size="1000px".color="red";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `width`, `height` and `cssText`. There is no property in CSS called "size". By using cssText you can change multiple properties without using jQuery( e.g `element.css({"height": "100px", "width": "100px"})`
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2as3get3/2/

```
<script type="text/javaScript>
  document.getElementById("makesmaller").onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("littlebox").style.cssText = "width: 100px; height: 100px; color: green;";
}
  document.getElementById("makebig").onclick  = function(){
  document.getElementById("littlebox").style.cssText = "width: 1000px;  height: 1000px; color:red; ";
};
  </script>
```

Comment: Why downvote? I explained the solution, set up a jsfiddle and showed Andy what he did wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no "size" style

There's width, height, fontSize, and I'm sure there's others, but not size

Here's what might do what you want.

```
document.getElementById("makesmaller").onclick=function(){
     var el = document.getElementById("bigbox");
     el.style.height="100px";
     el.style.width="100px";
     el.style.color="green";
}
```

Similarly for the makebig part

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation of a `size` property in CSS. What you are most likely looking for is the CSS `width` and `height` properties.
Javascript syntax for such an operation would reside in the following code:

```
var element = [HTML Element]; // Get HTML Element

var width, height; // Set width and height variables

element.style.width = width;
element.style.height = height;
```

To do so upon the calling of an `onclick` event, the resulting code would be written along the following lines:

```
// Listen for click event
element.addEventListener("click",
    function() {
        element.style.width = width; // Set new width
        element.style.height = height; // Set new height
    });
```

To do exactly what you are aiming for, your code would be based on this logic:

```
// Get buttons
var bigger = [HTML Element], 
    smaller = [HTML Element];

// Set size variables
var bigger_width, bigger_height;
var smaller_width, smaller_height;

// Add handlers
bigger.addEventListener("click",
    function() {
        element.style.width = bigger_width;
        element.style.height = bigger_height;
    });

smaller.addEventListener("click",
    function() [
        element.style.width = smaller_width;
        element.style.height = smaller_height;
    });
```

*Alternatively, one could use the `element.onclick = function() { }` syntax.*

Comment: Thanks alot user3412847